# Establishing database connection for testing between Spring and Travis

Tags: spring-boot, travis-ci

I am trying to get Travis CI to successfully run the database tests in my Spring Boot app, which pass in my local copy as they can connect to the SQL host (my university's server), but of course fail in Travis which cannot tunnel to this remote server by default.

To try and resolve this I have set application.properties to have a datasource pointing to what Travis documents as being its SQL setup:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/root
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and have set travis.yml to run SQL:

```
language: java
services:
   - mysql
```

However the build still hangs and eventually fails for the same reason as before. I have checked a similar question where the only suggestion was to build a local h2 database for testing, which is not suitable here as I need to have the tests clearly passing on Travis.

How can I setup a database connection for testing that is accepted by both Travis and Spring Boot?

Comment: "here the only suggestion was to build a local h2 database for testing, which is not suitable here as I need to have the tests clearly passing on Travis", just curious why? As this would be the exact use case for this.

Comment: the project we're doing requires us to have the tests passing on Travis as part of CI grading.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this step in .travis.yml

```
before_install:
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS your_database;'
```

and `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/your_database` in `application.properties`